# Menu Hamburger diferente

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

[image: Modelo]

Estou tentando fazer um menu desta forma (vide imagem), mas não sei como isso funciona direito ... Se alguém puder me mandar um exemplo ou me ajudar nessa questão, agradeço muito.

Comment: Tente ser mais claro em sua pergunta, adicione onde realmente você está enfrentando problemas, assim sua pergunta está muito ampla. _Não quer o código pronto né?_ acesse: [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Sugestão: *Comece*. Crie um menu, e coloque o código aqui. O pessoal costuma fazer muita coisa pelos outros (muitas vezes completas), mas se você não mostrar esforço nenhum de sua parte, você perde nossos melhores "respondedores".